# Infinite loop when I tried to make a word counter

Tags: loops, assembly, cpu-word, infinite, tasm

I was trying to make a word counter (counts how many words there are in the string) and I used the `jmp` instruction to go back to the `WORDCOUNT` label, but the problem is that it keeps making an infinite loop. When I add `jmp WORDCOUNT` before the `ADDCOUNTER`, it makes an infinite loop. What could be the cause of this? I would really appreciate it if someone can explain it to me. :)

```
; count the number of words in the string
        mov ax, 0000 
        mov bx, 0000 ; will contain the data
        mov cx, 0000 ; will count the number of words
        mov dx, 0000 ; erase all content to 0000
        lea bx, USERSTRING ; bx will contain the user string input
WORDCOUNT:
        mov al, [bx] ; al will contain bx data inside
        cmp al, "$" ; check if it is the end of the string already
        je ENDWORDCOUNT ; get out of the loop if done
        cmp al, " " ; if the value has space 20h
        je ADDCOUNTER ; then go to ADDCOUNTER to add
        inc bx ; hop to the next address one at a time
        jmp WORDCOUNT
    ADDCOUNTER:
            inc cx ; add cx with 1 because it means there is space
            jmp WORDCOUNT

ENDWORDCOUNT:
        call TODECIMAL
        mov cx, ax ; ax transfers the decimal version here
        mov word ptr HOWMANYWORDS, cx ; this one will be turned into a decimal dude help me here huhuhu
        lea dx, HOWMANYWORDS
        call PRINTF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you find a space character you jump to `ADDCOUNTER`, where you increase `cx` but not `bx`, so upon jumping back to `WORDCOUNT` you'll be reading the same character again (i.e. the space), and so on, for all eternity.
You'll need to have an `inc bx` in the `ADDCOUNTER` case as well.

Comment: I'd increase `bx` just after `mov al,[bx]`